# Coldfusion Mongo Db

Tags: mongodb, coldfusion, coldfusion-2021

after ColdFusion 2021 Hotfix 12, my MongoDB code stopped working. In another environment, ColdFusion 2021 with Hotfix 10 is installed, and I don't encounter this issue in the test environment where I use the same code and the same database. When I execute the query, it returns an empty response, but I am sure that the data is present.

```
<cfscript> 
  db = getmongoservice("xxx").db("xxx"); // create a db 
  response = db.xxx.find().sort( { createdAt: -1 } ).limit(1).toArray()[1];
</cfscript>
```

Comment: If you can reproduce this in a simple case and see the same issue in HF12 but not in HF11, I would suggest submitting at big report. Http://Tracker.adobe.com

Answer (score 0):

When I downgrade to hotfix 10, the problem is resolved. It does not work with hotfix 11 and above

Comment: Welcome! If your answer solves the problem please consider accepting it as an answer. This will benefit future users who find your question in a search. They will see that a solution exists. For details on accepting answers see this [Stack Exchange post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).